# Pandas - Remove duplicates while filling specific rows (fillna by rows)

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, data-cleaning

I have a DataFrame which looks like this:

```
>> pd.DataFrame([["Anne", True, 1, "A"],["Bert", True, None, "B"],["Conan", False, 0, None],["Bert", None, None, None],["Conan", None, None, "C"],["Bert",None,2,None]], columns = ["Name", "Bool", "Int", "Char"])

    Name   Bool  Int  Char
0   Anne   True  1.0     A
1   Bert   True  NaN     B
2  Conan  False  0.0  None
3   Bert   None  NaN  None
4  Conan   None  NaN     C
5   Bert   None  2.0  None
```

What I want is to

1. Remove duplicates based on a column
2. In the removal process, keep the rows with less NaNs
3. If possible, fill the Nan values using a set of Rows (given a condition)

I can do (1) and (2), I cannot understand how to do the (3)

### Part 1 & 2

```
>>> def remove_duplicates_smartly(df, columns):
        df.assign(nan_count= df.isna().sum(axis=1), inplace=True) 
        df.sort_values(['nan_count'], inplace=True).drop_duplicates(columns, inplace=True)
        df.drop(columns=["nan_count"], inplace=True)
        return df

>>> my_df = pd.DataFrame([["Anne", True, 1, "A"],["Bert", True, None, "B"],["Conan", False, 0, None],["Bert", None, None, None],["Conan", None, None, "C"],["Bert",None,2,None]], columns = ["Name", "Bool", "Int", "Char"])
>>> remove_duplicates_smartly(my_df)

>>> remove_duplicates_smartly(my_df, ["Name"])

    Name   Bool  Int  Char
0   Anne   True  1.0     A
1   Bert   True  NaN     B
2  Conan  False  0.0  None
```

### Desired output

The current missing values can be filled using the soon-to-be-deleted rows. The new values should be taken from the soon-to-be-deleted rows who have a value (selected by the user) in common (in this case, the Name)

```
    Name   Bool  Int  Char
0   Anne   True  1.0     A
1   Bert   True  2.0     B
2  Conan  False  0.0     C
```

Comment: Is possible some group has only `NaN`s ?

Comment: @jezrael it is not, in my case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For replace values per group specified by columns is possible use custom lambda function with forward and back filling `None` or `NaN`s values.

Solution working correctly if grouping with columns filled with non missing values like `Name`.

```
columns = 'Name'
df = df.groupby(columns).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates(columns)
print (df)
    Name   Bool  Int Char
0   Anne   True  1.0    A
1   Bert   True  2.0    B
2  Conan  False  0.0    C
```

Comment: Smart, and clean.  Thanks a lot